# How to fix image "failed to load resource: too many HTTP redirects" from safari on google web app

Tags: ios, image, google-apps-script, web-applications, safari

I have created a google web app that contains a form for users to fill out their details. One of the elements of the form is a image that grabs the users photo id stored in the google drive. It works perfectly fine on Chrome & Android but I'm getting nowhere with Safari & IOS.

The way it grabs the users photo is when they first open the webpage, they are prompted to enter a pin, the web app then checks a google sheet to see if its correct. If it is, it grabs the results along the corresponding row, one of these results is the google photo link. It then throws this link into the image tag. The link I'm using is https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=[photo id here]. The photo displays perfectly on chrome and android but I have just tested it on safari and IOS and only the alt appears. I am getting the error Failed to load resource: too many HTTP redirects.

```
var LPHOTO = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=[photo id here]"
<img id="lphoto" src=LPHOTO alt="Photo ID" width="300" height="200" >
```

As I mentioned earlier, when tested on Chrome or android devices the image appears instantly, but when its used on safari or IOS the image fails to load.

Comment: 1.Try clearing cookies and cache on the browser 2. Enable third party cookies/content, if disabled.

Comment: There's an offered solution for this error using Safari - [If Safari can't open the page because too many redirects occurred](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203370). Kindly check the documentation for more details. Your error might occur when you open a page that is redirected to another page, which is then redirected to open the original page.